# Not able to send email using Javamailserver, Connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email from my Spring boot application. Here are my configuration properties.

```
spring:
application:
  name: spring-base-template
profiles:
active: ${env:local}
 mail:
  default-encoding: UTF-8
  host: company.host.name
  username: myusername@domain.com
  password: mypassword
  port: 587
  properties:
    mail:
      smtp:
        auth: true
        starttls:
          enable: true
        socketFactory:
          port: 465
          class: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
          fallback: false
  protocol: smtp
  test-connection: false
```

My sample code look like this

```
 try {
        SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mail.setTo("myusername@domain.com");
        mail.setFrom("myusername@domain.com");
        mail.setSubject("Registration Confirmation");
        mail.setText("You are registered Successfully! Thank you for being with us!");
        javaMailSender.send(mail);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I try to send the email, following is the exception

```
    org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: company.host.name, port: 587;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: company.host.name, port: 587;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset; message exception details (1) 
are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 
company.host.name, port: 587;
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  Most likely you have a firewall or anti-virus product that is preventing you from connecting.

Comment: The problem here is that the main server isn't running at the IP:port you specified. EIther it isn't running at all or the IP:port isn't correct.

Comment: @user207421 I took the server name from the microsoft outlook, I'm trying to send a sample email from my email id itsef